# jquery clickable icon dropdown div with a searchbox inside

Tags: jquery, html, css

Imagine an icon when you click it , appears a div with a search box inside of it below it. How can I achieve such a thing? The problem is making being able to make the icon have a drop down div.

```
<div class="searchbox">
<input placeholder="search..." type="text" /></div>
<select name="icon" class="default" tabindex="20">
<option value="">  </option> 

<option value=""> </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am ready to imagine, but What have you tried yet???

Answer (score 0):

May this glorious icon dropdown shatter the limits of your imagination and bring users of this search bar great euphoria.

http://jsfiddle.net/5udptx82/

HTML

```
<section class="fantastic-wrapper">
    <div id="glorious-icon"></div>
    <div class="glorious-dropdown hidden">
        <div class="searchbox">
            <input placeholder="search..." type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#glorious-icon:before {
    content:'☃';
}
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$('#glorious-icon').click( function() {
    $(this).siblings('.glorious-dropdown').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `.toggle()`?

Comment: Because the jQuery animations engine needs to go.